# Trying to deploy next.js app on netlify - Command failed with exit code 1: next build && next export

Tags: javascript, next.js, netlify

I have this landing page, and i put the code on a github repo, then, i tried to deploy it on netlify, but, this error keeps appearing.

```
6:53:00 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
6:53:00 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
6:53:00 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
6:53:00 PM: ​
6:53:00 PM:   Error message
6:53:00 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: next build && next export
6:53:00 PM: ​
6:53:00 PM:   Error location
6:53:00 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
6:53:00 PM:   next build && next export
6:53:00 PM: ​
6:53:00 PM:   Resolved config
6:53:00 PM:   build:
6:53:00 PM:     command: next build && next export
6:53:00 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
6:53:00 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/out
6:53:00 PM:     publishOrigin: ui
6:53:00 PM:   functions:
6:53:00 PM:     '*': {}
6:53:00 PM:   plugins:
6:53:00 PM:     - inputs: {}
6:53:00 PM:       origin: ui
6:53:00 PM:       package: '@netlify/plugin-nextjs'
6:53:00 PM: Caching artifacts
6:53:00 PM: Started saving node modules
6:53:00 PM: Finished saving node modules
6:53:00 PM: Started saving build plugins
6:53:00 PM: Finished saving build plugins
6:53:00 PM: Started saving pip cache
6:53:00 PM: Finished saving pip cache
6:53:00 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
6:53:00 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
6:53:00 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
6:53:00 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
6:53:00 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
6:53:00 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
6:53:00 PM: Started saving rust rustup cache
6:53:00 PM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
6:53:00 PM: Started saving go dependencies
6:53:00 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
6:53:03 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
6:53:03 PM: Creating deploy upload records
6:53:03 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
6:53:03 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
6:53:03 PM: Finished processing build request in 1m25.941100434s
```

This is my package json

```
{
  "name": "costureria-landing-page",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.12.1",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "next": "11.0.1",
    "next-images": "^1.8.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^8.32.0",
    "react-responsive": "^8.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "7.29.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.0.1"
  }
}
```

The command i'm trying to use is next build && next export, and i tried also npm run build, but i've had problems with all of them.

This is the github [repo](https://github.com/Diego-Mike/Costureria-Gloria) if you want to check for something else

What is going on and how can i fix this ? Thanks for your time

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**

I've tried to run next build && next export locally, and this was the error

```
info  - No "exportPathMap" found in "next.config.js". Generating map from "./pages"
Error: Image Optimization using Next.js' default loader is not compatible with `next export`.
  Possible solutions:
    - Use `next start` to run a server, which includes the Image Optimization API.
    - Use any provider which supports Image Optimization (like Vercel).
    - Configure a third-party loader in `next.config.js`.
    - Use the `loader` prop for `next/image`.
  Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/export-image-api
    at C:\Users\diego cifuentes\Desktop\Portafolio\Landing Pages\Costureria - Landing Page - Next.js\costureria-landing-page\node_modules\next\dist\export\index.js:14:785
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\diego cifuentes\Desktop\Portafolio\Landing Pages\Costureria - Landing Page - Next.js\costureria-landing-page\node_modules\next\dist\telemetry\trace\trace.js:6:584)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! costureria-landing-page@0.1.0 export: `next build && next export`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the costureria-landing-page@0.1.0 export script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\diego cifuentes\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-06T01_29_13_977Z-debug.log
```

Can i deploy to netlify using npm run build && npm run start then ? or what can i do so i can use `Image from next/image`

Comment: Is there an error log somewhere that may provide more details?

Comment: Yo, i just updated the post !

Comment: Your error is with the Image component from next. You need to configure a loader. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader

Comment: Exactly ! But i was using Image component, and i did not want to change that part of the project since i'm using too many images, so, i went to vercel and deployed it there, don't know why netlify is not that easy to deplot as vercel, but, besides that, thanks for the answer !

Comment: @Diego It's a limitation of the `next/image` component - `next/image`'s default loader is not supported when using `next export` (because it requires a running server). As @JoelHager said, you'll need to configure a custom loader instead.

Comment: The reason being is the next/image component utilizes Vercel serverless functions without loaders configured. Netlify doesn't have Vercel's serverless functions, so that's why you're running into this issue. You can easily use cloudinary/etc. to configure images, and there's a healthy free option.

Comment: Understood !

Yes, thanks for your answers community, i didn't know that limitation about Image component, thanks  again!